# What does the %System% in %System%\AcroIEHelper.dll mean?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I don't quite understand the `%System%`. Do I have to find the file `AcroIEHelper.dll` under this folder?

I had an instruction to delete this AcroIEHelper.dll.
But not sure if I have to look it under System folder...

```
%System%\AcroIEHelper.dll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an *environmental variable* in Windows. The most commonly known one is PATH but there are many others. You can find out what variables are set by opening the Command Prompt and typing `set`
.

If %System% is defined on your XP install (it is not on my Win7 install) then you should be able to type it into your Explorer bar or Run... or at the Command Prompt and it will translate to the correct folder.

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: It's like a placeholder for a real folder. When providing generic instructions you cannot assume that all Windows installations are identical. For example, some users may decide to install Windows on drive D instead of C, in which case the `%SystemRoot%` variable would contain something like `D:\WINDOWS` instead of the more common `C:\WINDOWS`. Standard environmental variables like these help remove inconsistencies between individual installations. I just checked an XP install and %SYSTEM% was not defined. Try using %SystemRoot% instead or provide a link to the instructions you refering to.